# How do I run a foreach against an array and include it in an SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to be able to get a value from an array and use it in an SQL query, and get information from those rows. My current code is like so:

```
$config['exclude_devices'] = array('1','5');
```

```
$exclude = $config['exclude_devices'];
foreach ($exclude as $excluded) {
    $deviceinformation = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE `device_id` NOT IN(" . $excluded . ")");
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($deviceinformation)) {
    // do stuff here
    // write to a variable for use in a table
}
```

However, this gives the output of devices 1,2,3,4.

If I move the `foreach` to include the `while`, it produces 2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4:

```
$exclude = $config['exclude_devices'];
foreach ($exclude as $excluded) {
    $deviceinformation = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE `device_id` NOT IN(" . $excluded . ")");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($deviceinformation)) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

How can I modify this code to produce only the devices that are not listed in the config?

Comment: This may be helpful for what you want to do - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: Select records where device_id is not `1` - selects all including `5`. Select records where device_id is not `5` - selects all including `1`.  Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In example 1:

You run:

```
SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE `device_id` NOT IN(3)
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE `device_id` NOT IN(5)
```

You then only fetch the second queries results so you should get back devices with non 5 for their ids.

I would use an `implode` so you exclude all ids you don't want.

```
$excluded = implode(',', $config['exclude_devices']);
$deviceinformation = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE `device_id` NOT IN(" . $excluded . ")");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($deviceinformation)) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/536862
SQL Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4ed47/2

Comment: I had tried explode, both with and without an array. ```implode``` works. Thanks a lot.